# How to get full match on regex and line number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-2.7

Ive got a regex that is meant to find all multilined comments and docstrings, so far it is currently only returning group 1 from the regex, what I want is the full match and corresponding line number, what would i have to change to find get these results?

code -

```
match = r'''(['"])\1\1[\d\D]*?\1{3}'''

textfile = open(file, 'r')
filetext = textfile.read()
textfile.close()
matches = re.findall(match, filetext)
print matches
```

example file on which I would be running this code on -

```
a = '\ttesting this file!'
b = "abc"
print a

def trigger():
    a = b'\r\n'
    b = "\t"


"""
dasdas
adasdsa
"""
class A:
    """
    dsadasd
    dsadas
    """
    def new():
        """
        dsadas
        :return:
        """
```

What the function returns -

```
['"', '"', '"']
```

Comment: `matches = [x.group() for x in re.finditer(match, filetext)]`

Comment: Not possible to get line number?

Comment: Not with regex.